# Bidirectional level shifter

Tags: clock, level-shifting

In my project I need a level shifter for a 3.6MHz clock.
The problem I have with my design is that in order to respect the requirement I have, my rise and fall time need to be <25.2ns

[image]

I used the following design, I tested first with the 2N7002 but it didn't even have the time to reach the 5V. When I simulate this design I have the following results:

[image]

Based on the simulation I should have a 18ns rise time and almost instant fall time, but when implemented in practice I get a 40ns rise time. Do you think there is another MOSFET transistor (SOT23 package) that would make me shave off few more nanoseconds or I should totally rebuild my design ?

Comment: Why are you using a bidirectional shifter for a unidirectional signal?

Comment: I used it because it was the only design I knew would work without introducing a voltage drop

Comment: Wouldn't your rise time have more to do with your pull-up resistors?  Or do you feel the MOSFET is turning off too slowly?

Comment: The rise time issue is due to the pull up and parasitic output capacitance of the MOSFET I think, that's why using the 2N7002A instead of 2N7002 improved the rise time a lot (Output capacitance is 4 times lower)

Comment: My first question is, do you even need a level shifter? What device produces the 3.3V clock and what is the 5V device it goes into? Have you checked that the 5V device is not already compatible with 3.3V input signal?

Comment: Yes I do need a level shifter the 3.3V clock is produced by a CPU and the 5V goes to a Smartcard (Smartcards can work with 1.8, 3.3, 5V but this one is a 5V)

Comment: Ah, I built my first bidirectional level shifter a couple of years ago, using 2N7000 and I found it good for my Rpi 100kHz I2C applications. Today I would use 2N7002. My applications are low speed so I never thought about rise/fall time etc. But why don't you google a faster MOSFET? I know 2N7000/7002 is a general purpose cheap thing. Are you sure it is difficult to find a quicker guy?

Comment: Ah, just now I googled for "high speed mosfet" and the first one came is ***25nS max***. So now I agree with you that you need to ask around. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: Risetime depends on R1+R2=2k and load <10 pF and gain depends on R2/R1 during transition.  If necessary (?) change R1 to 100 ohms and R2 to 470 Ohms

Comment: Cin of FET needs lower R1 ... which IC is the load?

Answer (score 1):

The FET pass gate level shifter is slow and is not suitable for the signal speeds you need.

Use a CMOS buffer chip that can work with 3.3V signal on input and will provide a 5V signal on output.

Since you now mentioned what you need it for, you should especially look for smartcard interface ICs that may provide you with many other benefits in addition to simply converting IO interface voltages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's what I suspected. I already have a design based on buffers that I validated. If you want to know more my idea was to design a Smartcard interface entirely in discrete component, because there is a shortage on SC ICs and I'm scared that buffers might lack sooner or later.